# 502 bad gateway - POST from C# but works fine in fiddler

Tags: c#, http, post

c# code in VS, I tried either WebClient, HttpClient OR HttpWebRequest, sending a post to an url, but always get 502 bad gateway error, however, the post works fine , return 200OK in fiddler or postman

BTW, same code works fine on another machine. guess sth wrong with my machine setting, anything I can check why?

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: I tried varies code, it all works on another machine, so I assume it is not a code issue?

Comment: Did you try to disable the firewall ?

Comment: all right, I am answering it myself, turns out it is a code issue but I am not sure why, I have to set client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

Comment: You can add a full answer to your question, then you can (and should) accept it after 48 hours. This will help other users who have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

all right, I am answering it myself, turns out it is a code issue but I am not sure why, I have to set client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;