# Couldn't establish a connection with HttpClient C# and TLS 1.x

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, httpclient, tls1.2

I am using Asp.net c#. I have an external API url, which does respond to specific url with `TLS 1.2/1.1` enabled. I want to consume that API from my `Web API`. I have written following code to access the same.

```
    public async Task<bool> Post(string oauth_signature, string oauth_consumer_key, string oauth_timestamp, string oauth_nonce, CheckKYCRequestModel payload)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        string url = "https://recycle.icicipruamc.com/Distributorsvcs/InvestorService.svc/JSON/CheckKYC?oauth_signature=" + oauth_signature + 
            "&oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key + "&oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "";

        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        return true;
    }
```

But I am unable to establish a connection and it is throwing ***"Could not reach to the server"*** error.

I tried doing the same thing from Fiddler and it is working perfectly, but doesn't work with `HttpClient`, even though the client IP address is same and TLS is enabled in both cases.

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You might want to redact that URL...

Comment: With http the headers in the first request determines the transfer parameters.  So you have to make the c# headers look like the fiddler headers.  The default headers in c# are not the same as fiddler.

Comment: Does the network you are trying this from use an HTTP proxy? Also, if you enable Fiddler and use it as a proxy, what do you see when you try to hit the API using `HttpClient`?

Comment: @jdweng I don't see any headers in the images or code - what headers are you specifically referring to? Also what do you mean by "transfer parameters"?

Comment: @cocowalla when i kept open and use proxy, it shows Tunnel to request with request type CONNECT and with response 502. And Not sure about Http or https proxy.

Comment: Also, unless you're using a really old .NET Framework (<4.5.1,IIRC), you shouldn't usually specify SSL/TLS protocols using `SecurityProtocol` - instead, you should leave it up to the OS to negotiate a secure channel. If you really do need to specify protocols for some reason, you should definitely not use SSL 3.0, and should avoid TLS 1.0 if possible.

Comment: @Cocowalla it is mendatory to use tls 1.2/1.1, otherwise it won't connect

Comment: @Bimal Das, open Internet Explorer and look at the network settings - that should tell you if you're behind a non-transparent HTTP proxy or not. Fairly sure you can also see in Fiddler settings if it's chaining to an upstream proxy. HTTP 502 certainly can be proxy related

Comment: If it's mandatory to use TLS 1.1/1.2, then you really shouldn't be specifying SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. Also, you should still leave it up to the OS, as it will use TLS 1.2 if it can.

Comment: @cocowalla might be it is proxy related. But I don't know how to disable. Support team also told me once

Comment: Found a duplicate question, you can try the answer from it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357712/25758. If that doesn't do it, and your network does use a proxy, it might be that you need to manually specify the proxy in the C# code

Comment: @Cocowalla didn't work, I tried that too. :(

Comment: Which one, there were 2 things to try in my last comment :)

Comment: @Cocowalla I tried client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false; before calling

Comment: @Cocowalla proxy is disabled on my server I checked

Comment: @Cocowalla Hi, finally the issue is resolved. The url you given to the comment solved the issue. Thank you so so much. You are awesome :) :) :)